# suckerfish menu in js not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get [suckerfish navigation menu](http://be.twixt.us/jquery/suckerFish.php) working but it is not `fading` as shown in the demo.

I've put my revision on JSbin: http://jsbin.com/usabo/3

I feel that jquery is not even being triggered

Answer (score 0):

This might get you closer:
http://jsbin.com/usabo/6

Your JS had an error in the hover() function.

Good luck.